# double summation and rank by first attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, grouping, pandas-groupby

I have done a double summation based on "CPTY" and "currency" group using the following code:

```
brkrcy=data.groupby(['CPTY','currency'], as_index=False).agg({"Gross Loan Amount": "sum"})
```

which lead to the following output:

```
      CPTY currency  Gross Loan Amount
0     BARC      EUR       2.683000e+09
1     BARC      GBP       6.091100e+09
2     BARC      SEK       2.174349e+08
3     BARC      USD       5.993229e+09
4     BARC      ZAR       1.126837e+08
5     BMON      GBP       7.846989e+06
6     BMON      USD       7.758432e+08
7      BNP      EUR       3.204291e+09
8      BNP      GBP       2.953117e+09
9      BNP      JPY       2.642923e+08
10     BNP      USD       3.511912e+09
11   CALIP      EUR       5.598966e+06
12   CALIP      GBP       3.319806e+09
13   CALIP      USD       8.736326e+08
14   CANTR      USD       3.142870e+08
15    CIBC      CAD       5.545886e+08
16    CIBC      GBP       1.099860e+09
17    CITI      CZK       2.941352e+07
```

I am looking to rank the table "brkrcy" based on the sum of "Gross Loan Amount" of "CPTY" first then "currency" .Note that i have an older version of pandas so "sort_values" do not work for me. I have tried

```
brkrcy.sort(['Gross Loan Amount'], ascending=[False])
```

but it ranks based on the "Gross Loan Amount" only. The desired output should start with the highest total "Gross Loan Amount" value of "CPTY" first and then rank "currency" in descending order. It is like a double ranking starting by "CPTY" then "currency"

Comment: If I am not mistaken, pandas keeps the order if two values are identical. Have you tried `brkrcy.sort(['currency'], ascending=[False]).sort(['Gross Loan Amount'], ascending=[False]) `?

Comment: @maow  thanks. I have tried your answer but it does the sorting on "Gross Loan Amount" only. it is not the double sorting i am looking for.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand correctly what you want. Could you give the first one or to lines of the desired output for your example?

Answer (score 0):

here is another example to make myself clear

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'A','A', 'B', 'B','B'], 'b': ['A1', 'A2','A3' ,'B1', 'B2','B3'], 'c': ['2','3','4','5','6','1'] })

>>> df
   a   b  c
0  A  A1  2
1  A  A2  3
2  A  A3  4
3  B  B1  5
4  B  B2  6
5  B  B3  1
```

desired output

```
>>> df
       a   b  c
    4  B  B2  6
    3  B  B1  5
    5  B  B3  1       
    2  A  A3  4
    1  A  A2  3
    0  A  A1  2
```

As you can see it is a double ranking based on column a then column b. We first start with the highest which is B and within B we also start with the highest which is B2

Comment: please guys can i get a response on this or shall i post another question? thank you